# C# Iterate and Compare multiple nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an XML file, I need to iterate through the XML file and compare nodes attribute value. Condition is the attribute in the element of the node should have a particular value set.

Let me make this more easy to understand by showing an example below:

```
<Node name="SomeName">
<Element attribute="somevalue"/>
</Node>
<Node name="SomeNameMore">
 <Element attribute="somevalue"/>
</Node>
<Node name="SomeNameEtc.">
 <Element attribute="somevaluenotmatch"/>
</Node>
<Node name="SomeName">
 <Element attribute="somevalue"/>
</Node>
```

There are 100's of similar nodes in the XML file.

1st Condition: Match on attribute 'somevalue'

2nd Condition: Compare all the nodes in 1st condition (result) for the attribute name in the Node.

I have done as below:

```
        XmlTextReader Reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\TEST\test.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Reader);

        XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
        XmlElement rootNode = doc.DocumentElement;

        XPathExpression expr;

        expr = nav.Compile("//Element[@attribute='somevalue']");
        XPathNodeIterator iterator = nav.Select(expr);

        foreach (XmlElement item in iterator)
        {
          //how do go back to node here (whose element has attribute 'somevalue' and compare with the next node if the attribute 'name' of Node matches
          } ;
```

Comment: means you want to retrieve all those `Node`s that `Element` have same value matches with `somevalue`, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct and then also compare the Node's attribute 'name' in the extracted data.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq which will easily create a dictionary of the needed values

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Node")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => (string)y.Element("Element").Attribute("attribute"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            //or if you have multiple items with same key
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict2 = doc.Descendants("Node")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => (string)y.Element("Element").Attribute("attribute"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to perform what you're looking for, I'm not sure if I understood correctly the second scenario, but  I'll share an example for the first, it may help you find the good way to do it:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("your_xmlFile_path");
var query = from c in xml.Root.Descendants("Node").Descendants("Element")
            where c.Attribute("attribute").Value == "somevalue"
            select c;
```

I tested the query for you, it returns the correct number of "somevalue" elements.

**EDIT**
You can retrieve the name instead of the value of an attribute by replacing the

```
c.Attribute("attribute").Value
```

By

```
c.Attribute("attribute").Name
```

Hope this helps, good luck